# Irrespective of what application owns active window, whenever I hit F1, Firefox dialog comes up

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, xfce, firefox, xfwm4

No matter what window is active (even if it has nothing to do with Firefox), when I press <kbd>F1</kbd>, a Firefox dialog titled "Choose User Profile" pops up.

This means that I cannot use <kbd>F1</kbd> with any other program.

How can I disable Firefox's trapping of all <kbd>F1</kbd>'s?

FWIW, my OS is Debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this addon to disable or modify any keyboard shortcuts: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/